# OpenCart Adding Class to Product Options

Tags: php, opencart

Currently trying to wrap my head around something in OpenCart. It's been years since I have done anything with PHP so having a little trouble. I'm redirecting clicks of href links in to the same div the page is in but some href links need to be ignored because they add elements to the page. I'm ignoring them with a not() selector via my own class I am adding to links I want to ignore, though having trouble adding a class to some links.

For example on the products form for adding products there's an option tab which lets you add different options such as check boxes and date/time. The drop down menu for adding these options has some href links that I can't seem to figure out how to add a class to.

Here's a pastebin to the product_form.php: http://pastebin.com/Fchxw8XG

Here's a look at the actual pages html through chrome dev tools: [image]

I just need to figure out how to add a class called navtab to these dropdown links so I can ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I didn't even need to do anything directly to the URL. Instead I am just detecting when a link is clicked in that div (the option dropdown is the only links in there) and I am adding a class on click and then processing the rest of my script.

Here's what I originally had;

```
$("#products").on("click", "a:not(.navtab, #)", function (e) {
    $("#products").load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So it will ignore any link with the class navtab, but I needed to add the class so before this runs I run this:

```
$(function(){
    var option = $('#tab-option');
    option.delegate('a','click',function(){
        option.addClass('navtab');
        $(this).addClass('navtab');
    });
});
```